# Flash and javascript, Lightbox

Tags: javascript, actionscript, lightbox, flash-cs4

I'm working with a mask within a flash document in which text can be entered to create a news archive. Typically, there will be a blurb, and then a link within dynamic text that opens a new web browser tab.

What I want to do instead opening a separate tab is to open a `lightbox` overlay within the same web page.Up to now, I've used `ActionScript` within other flash documents to trigger `lightbox` windows, but I don't think that's going to be an option with this mask.

I saw that another user had a similar question. One person suggested an `actionscript` response and buttons. That's not going to work from within the dynamic text in this case, I think.

This time, I tried plugging in the `lightbox` code into the "link" box for the dynamic text. But Flash really objects. It hides or erases all the dynamic text from the point where I inserted the `lightbox` trigger forward, and needless to say I can't get to the `lighbtox` trigger within the `.swf` file, let alone get it to load.

I don't know how to copy or post the raw code for the dynamic code, so instead I've made a simple copy of the .swf file that should show what I'm trying to do, and copies of what I believe are the relevant `actionscript` sections. First, the link to the `.swf:` available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35549996/ForStackOverflow.swf):

I went around and around with stack-overflow's interface, trying to paste in what I believe is the relevant `actionscript`, but it came out very messy and difficult to read. Here's a link to to the `ActionScript`:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35549996/ActionScriptForStackOverflow.txt

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: i don't really get what you're trying to achieve?! as nate said, some code would probably help. also your title talks about JS+AS but in the text you're only talking about AS.

Comment: I don't know how to copy or post the raw code for the dynamic code, so instead I've made a simple copy of the .swf file that should show what I'm trying to do. It's available here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35549996/ForStackOverflow.swf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something other than the default when a link in a text is clicked, you can define a listener for the TextEvent.LINK event:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TextEvent.html